# Why the condition doesn't occur?

Tags: c++

The simple C++ code:

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"
#include <float.h>

double ctok(double c){
    const double koef_c_2_k = 274.15;
    double k = c + koef_c_2_k;
    if(k < -koef_c_2_k) error("Output abroad range of admissible values.");
    return k;
}

int main(){
    cout << "Max double value: " << DBL_MAX << endl;
    double c = 0;
    cout << "Celsius: ";
    cin >> c;
    double k = ctok(c);
    cout << "Kelvin: " << k << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> bush@host-nix:~/cpp/bs/5/5.2$ ./a.out
>   Max double value: 1.79769e+308
>   Celsius: 0
>   Kelvin: 274.15
>   bush@host-nix:~/cpp/bs/5/5.2$ ./a.out
>   Max double value: 1.79769e+308
>   Celsius: 100
>   Kelvin: 374.15
>   bush@host-nix:~/cpp/bs/5/5.2$ ./a.out 
>   Max double value: 1.79769e+308
>   Celsius: -100
>   Kelvin: 174.15
>   bush@host-nix:~/cpp/bs/5/5.2$ ./a.out 
>   Max double value: 1.79769e+308
>   Celsius: 1.79769e+308
>   Kelvin: **1.79769e+308**
>   bush@host-nix:~/cpp/bs/5/5.2$

At the last case I set the max value for the Celsius, and I have waited the error message, but I got the wrong Kelvin's value. Why it happened?
Thank you.

Comment: `1.79769e+308` + `274.15` seems like you're adding a cup of water to the ocean.

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you add a value to the maximum value a double can hold?  Would that very large value be less than -274.15?

Comment: If I add the 1 to the **double** maximum value, then I must to get the minimum **double** value. Or I am not right?

Comment: @Bush No. You're confusing this with the overflow behavior of integers in 2's complement presentation. Floating point numbers are an entirely different beast.

Comment: @RetiredNinja If you know he's not right, why not leave an actual *answer*? It's a Q&A site. Smug attitude like this does not help anyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

`1.79769e+308` + `274.15` seems like you're adding a cup of water to the ocean.

The precision of the real numbers is limited, and your comparison is not sensible in the computer world.

You can not use a single `double` variable for very small and very large numbers simultaneously. Define the range, your solution should be microscopic or macroscopic.

Comment: That value is not sensible in the physical world, either.

Comment: Cup of water?  Adding an atom to the known universe would not be remotely close :)